# Windows 10 Task Scheduler: Do not run task if high CPU

Tags: cpu-usage, task-scheduler

I have a task that runs when I'm not on my pc that uses a lot of resources, but I would like it not to run if my computer already has a high CPU usage, if the program is already running, for example. Or if I have something else going on that uses a lot op processing power.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What research have you done into this? Where are you stuck? :)

Comment: At first I looked throught the menu. Couldn't find anything that even hinted at a possibility like this. I've also googled quite a bit, but I haven't managed to find anything about this.

Comment: by default Tasks run at low priority. Export the task to XML, change the priority to 1 save the XML, delete the task and import the XML and look if the task now runs.

Comment: I'd rather it wouldn't run at all, instead of running at a lower priority. Something like this would be cool:
if (CPU.load < 90%) {run} else {don't run}